# Why is Akka Streams swallowing my exceptions?

Tags: scala, exception, akka-stream

Why is the exception in

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source

object TestExceptionHandling {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()(defaultActorSystem)

    Source(List(1, 2, 3)).map { i =>
      if (i == 2) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Please, don't swallow me!")
      } else {
        i
      }
    }.runForeach { i =>
      println(s"Received $i")
    }
  }
}
```

silently ignored? I can see that the stream gets stopped after printing `Received 1`, but nothing is logged. Note that the problem is not the logging configuration in general, as I see a lot of output if I set `akka.log-config-on-start = on` in my `application.conf` file.

Comment: You're throwing the exception away since you ignore the return value of `runForeach`.

Comment: @ViktorKlang thanks for pointing that out, I've just updated my answer!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm now using a custom `Supervision.Decider` that makes sure exceptions are properly logged, that can be set up like this:

```
val decider: Supervision.Decider = { e =>
  logger.error("Unhandled exception in stream", e)
  Supervision.Stop
}

implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
val materializerSettings = ActorMaterializerSettings(actorSystem).withSupervisionStrategy(decider)
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer(materializerSettings)(actorSystem)
```

Also, as has been pointed out by [Vikor Klang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227803/viktor-klang), in the example given above, the exception could also be "caught" via

```
Source(List(1, 2, 3)).map { i =>
  if (i == 2) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Please, don't swallow me!")
  } else {
    i
  }
}.runForeach { i =>
  println(s"Received $i")
}.onComplete {
  case Success(_) =>
    println("Done")
  case Failure(e) =>
    println(s"Failed with $e")
}
```

Note however, that this approach won't help you with

```
Source(List(1, 2, 3)).map { i =>
  if (i == 2) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Please, don't swallow me!")
  } else {
    i
  }
}.to(Sink.foreach { i =>
  println(s"Received $i")
}).run()
```

since `run()` returns `Unit`.

Comment: `run()` only returns `Unit` because it keeps the materialied value of the "left" side (Keep.left) by default. if you had used: toMat(Sink.foreach(…))(Keep.right) then it would work again.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar questions when I started using akk-streams. `Supervision.Decider` helps but not always.

Unfortunately it doesn't catch exceptions thrown in `ActionPublisher`. I see it handled, `ActorPublisher.onError` is called but it doesn't reach `Supervision.Decider`. It works with simple Stream provided in documentation.

Errors also don't reach actor if I use `Sink.actorRef`.

And for the sake of experiment I tried following sample

```
val stream = Source(0 to 5).map(100 / _)
stream.runWith(Sink.actorSubscriber(props))
```

In this case exception was caught by Decider but never reached actor subscriber.

Overall I think it's inconsistent behavior. I cannot use one mechanism for handling errors in Stream.

My original SO question: [Custom Supervision.Decider doesn't catch exception produced by ActorPublisher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32290285/226895)

And here is akka issue where it's tracked: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/18359

Answer (score 0):

I had a different issue with Akka Streams swallowing my exceptions. I'll post it here since this is the top Google result.

In a case like this, where `source` is a `Source[ByteString, Any]`:

```
source.runWith(StreamConverters.fromOutputStream(() => outputStream))
```

This returns a Future[IOResult]. If the write to the output stream fails (for example, the source fails), then the Future will still return a Success. In this case, you actually have to check the IOResult for the error:

```
source.runWith(StreamConverters.fromOutputStream(() => output)).
      map(ior => {
        if (!ior.wasSuccessful) 
          throw new RuntimeException(ior.getError)
      })
```

The result of this will be a failed Future with the correct exception.